# Preserve column order in Apify Python actor

Tags: python, apify

I'm trying to store a pandas dataframe in Apify and preserve the column order. The column order is correct in my dataframe, then I use the following commands to store the data:

```
df_output = df.to_json(orient = 'records',  date_format = 'iso')
default_dataset_client.push_items(df_output)
```

The data then gets stored with alphabetically sorted columns, instead of the original order I had in the dataframe.

Interestingly enough, the JSON format preview shows the right order, but if I download the CSV or Excel file, the column order is alphabetic.

[JSON file preview with correct column order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o18uh.png)

[HTML preview with alphabetic (incorrect) column order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3fYR.png)

Any ideas on how to preserve the column orders in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apify automatically orders columns in datasets and you unfortunately can't affect this. If you really need to have your columns ordered, you'll have to resort to some work-around.

I think the easiest way I can suggest is adding a prefix to each column name in such a way that after alphabetical sort, they will be kept in place - for example, name your columns `01_Farm name`, `02_Crop`, `03_Category` etc.